# how to insert checkbox value to database in python

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

In the front end they are selecting multiple checkboxes i.e;(district,taluk)
,so how can i get the values to the backend and how to save in the database.

note: I want to write this code based on definition not generics

this is my models

```
class Example(models.Model):
 district = models.CharField(max_length=20)
 taluk = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

if we give input in json format like

```
     {
     "Bangalore" :{

            "dodballapura",
            "   Hosakote"
         }
      }
```

then it should save in database and
in the above example bangalore is the district and remaining are talukas

Comment: Your input is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Thank you,then how can i send my json format for this type of data, i am new for django so it will be helpul for me

Comment: You can use this format    `{ "Bangalore" :[ "dodballapura", "Hosakote"] }`.  It is easy to verify your JSON from this address [json-formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) .

Comment: How does your serializer looks like? Did you created a custom `create()` method under your serializer class?